# Riemann - Hurwitz Formula for topology.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I am quite confused about the notion of branch points at infinity? and even in general the idea of branch points? I know branch points to be where points diverges to infinity.

Could someone please explain in this to me in terms of the Riemann - Hurwitz Formula?

Comment: To start, do you understand the complex $n$th power mapping $z \mapsto z^{n}$ for $n \geq 2$? Do you understand unbranched covering spaces? (Note: The concepts of "branch points" and "points at infinity" are logically independent; neither implies the other.)

Comment: Sorry, i feel helpless i do not....  understand those concepts.